# Send mail with mail and erb gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, mail-gem

I'm trying to send an email using the Mail gem and the ERB gem but I'm getting all the time the this error `TypeError Exception: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer`

I read the Mail Gem documentation and the ERB Documentation, and I followed their instructions but it is not working.

This is the method, `email` is the destination, and `errors` is an Array that contains possible errors that may have occurred (is empty if there were not any problems)

```
def self.send_file(email, errors)
    @errors = errors
    if errors.any?
      subject = 'There has been an error'
      template = %(
                     <html>
                     <p>Sorry, these errors occured:</p>
                     <ul>
                       <% @errors.each do |error| %>
                          <li><%= error %></li>
                       <% end %>
                     </ul>
                  </html>
                      ).gsub(/^ {2}/, '')

    else
      subject = 'Everything is okey'
      template = %(
                   <html>
                     <p> Everything it's okay! </p>
                   </html>
      ).gsub(/^ {2}/, '')
    end
    message = ERB.new(template, trim_mode: '<%>')
    @errors = errors
    mail = Mail.new do
      from ENV['NOTIFICATIONS_EMAIL']
      to email
      subject subject
      html_part do
        content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        body message.run(binding)
      end
    end
    mail.deliver
  end
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Can you write here the params `email` and `errors` you're sending to that method?

Comment: @SgtPepper I added that information to the post

Comment: You can't use ERB binding with a class method.

Comment: I think what @SgtPepper wants to see is an example of what you send in `email` & `errors`, not just a description of what you send.